# How to check whether a site is using adwords progmatically?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize, google-ads-api

I am trying to write a web scrappers and wanted to know is there any way where I can check whether the site is using google adwords or not.
Can we check this in HTML or by making a curl request or using Mechanize by any chance. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you search for the JS includes that Adwords uses on the page?

Comment: No this is not necessary that there is a js inclusion. I have seen a site which is listed in google ads but there is no js inclusion in the viewsource.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not any client side code *required* for the use of Adwords.  If you're not tracking anything from Adwords clicks then there will be no evidence on your site of you using Adwords.

Many sites will set up some sort of goal tracking for Adwords clicks, but this will just be snippets of code on selective pages.  Adwords tracking works by seeting cookies in Google's domain and then a script letting those cookies be read when a goal action is performed, so unless you just happen to be scraping a page where such codes reside, then you can't really tell from client side code.

Aside from scraping Google and looking for their results, which is against Google's TOS, then there's not a way to really tell.